# custom kivy event issues

Tags: python, events, kivy

I am having trouble understanding kivy's custom events. I am making a simple music player using kivy and I want some basic functionality: when a song ends, the next one plays. Kivy's sound class provides 2 events, `on_press` and `on_stop`.

Obviously, the correct choice here would be `on_stop`. However, this event is triggered both when the song ends naturally and when the user stops it manually. Thing is, I don't want the latter to happen, so I decided I should create a custom event. The resources available online to help me understand custom events are very few and confusing. Here's the example in the kivy docs:

```
class MyWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_swipe')

    def on_swipe(self):
        pass

def on_swipe_callback(*largs):
    print('my swipe is called', largs)
w = MyWidget()
w.dispatch('on_swipe')
```

So, we have the event (`on_swipe`) and an event handler (`on_swipe_callback`). When is this event supposed to be triggered? How do I define that? Let's say I want my event to be called `on_finish`, and I want it to be triggered when a song reaches the end of its duration. How and where do I write the details about that? I'd appreciate it if someone can help me understand how these events work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is triggered exactly when [`dispatch`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.dispatch) is called. What is missing in the bit of code in your question is the `bind`ing. You'd have something like

```
w = MyWidget()
w.bind(on_swipe=on_swipe_callback)
```

This tells `w` to call `on_swipe_callback` when the event `on_swipe` occurs.

Regarding your original question, this may be more difficult than it looks, because at the time of an `on_stop` the current position within a sound is not known.
A rather hackish solution might be to use [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) to schedule a function that checks whether the sound is still playing just before the end of the sound. Of course, this would be off e.g. if the user seeks. In the end, you might have to directly change the `Sound` class in `kivy.audio` to generate new events.

Another option would be to check in your `on_stop` callback if the Stop button was pressed in your UI. If it wasn't, then the song ended “naturally”. You'd set a flag in your `on_press` handler for the button and clear it in your `on_stop` handler.

Comment: Thanks. It seems creating a custom event would complicate things. To be honest i thought of editing the on_press handler myself, but i wasn't quite sure how to make it happen. Do i have to override the on_stop handler, or do i have to edit the kivy library itself?

Comment: No, you don't overwrite the handler. You use [`bind`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind) as in my answer to attach a function you write to the widget (or, more precisely, to an instance of `EventDispatcher`).